# How does the special variable "this" know exactly which Object to refer to in a program in JAVA?

Tags: java, oop, variables, object, this

If the special variable `this` refers to an Object in a variable/method that is being used.  How does it know exactly which object it must refer to out of various objects in a program?

Answer (score 3):

The mechanism is almost disappointingly simple.

Each instance method actually takes one more argument than you declare for it, and that extra argument is assigned to `this`. Java syntax just thinly disguises this. When you write

```
list.get(0);
```

you have actually written

```
get(list, 0);
```

in a slightly modified way. The Java runtime resolves which `get` method to call by inspecting the type of that first argument and locating the appropriate `get` method in its class.

Comment: nice answer as usual @MarkoTopolnik

Answer (score 2):

`this` points to the [**current** object **instance** that it is used in](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3).

If you define a class `A` with a `method()` that contains a `this` reference then you create two instances of the class

```
 A a1 = new A();
 A a2 = new A();
```

If you call `a1.method()` then `this` will refer to `a1`, if you call `a2.method()` then `this` will refer to `a2`

Answer (score 1):

From `JAVA LANGUAGE SPECIFICATION`

> The keyword this may be used only in the body of an instance method,
>   instance initializer, or constructor, or in the initializer of an
>   instance variable of a class. If it appears anywhere else, a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> When used as a primary expression, the keyword this denotes a value
>   that is a reference to the object for which the instance method was
>   invoked (§15.12), or to the object being constructed.
>
> The type of this is the class C within which the keyword this occurs.
>
> At run time, the class of the actual object referred to may be the
>   class C or any subclass of C.
>
> The keyword this is also used in a special explicit constructor
>   invocation statement, which can appear at the beginning of a
>   constructor body (§8.8.7).

You can also refer to [`Oracle Tutorials`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
A a = new A(); 
a.doSomething(i)  // is same as calling doSomething(a, i).
```

So, internally `this` refers to "a". The first argument to the function will be the object (there will only be one method that will be used by all objects). So, argument `o` will be the current object which has called this function.

Answer (score 0):

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within an instance method or a constructor by using this.

[Oracle Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a very important keyword that can differentiate between parent and child class objects.  `this` refers to the present context in which object has too be referred to..!!